# WordPress contact 7 with negative response

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have created a website using WordPress. I use a GoDaddy hosting and a plugin WP-Mail-SMTP, which helps me to configure SMTP. I have disable all cache plugins.

Right now I have a problem with my contact form (plugin Contact form 7). When I fill all fields and click a submit button, I get messages: "There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later."

I get next JSON answer from my server:

```
captcha:null
into:"#wpcf7-f31-p1401-o1"
mailSent: false
message: "There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later."
```

I receive emails from this forms, but I can not fix issues with server response and negative answers under my form: https://www.screencast.com/t/ReyXMwJLRS.  I try to disable/enable captcha, but it does not help.

Can somebody advice with this. I have checked all recommendation from https://contactform7.com/, but can not find a solution.

Best regards.

Comment: Can somebody help with it?

Comment: You configured WP-mail-SMTP according to the godaddy right ? There can be issue with godaddy, but WP-Mail-SMTP solve that problem. Could you share a screenshot of mail config tab of CF7 ?

Comment: Yes, I have used SMTP settings from GoDaddy: relay-hosting.secureserver.net, port: 25.

https://www.screencast.com/t/McHlmrWuSa

Comment: You need to use SMTP authentication as I know

Comment: I am not sure, I wrote to GoDaddy support and they upload a test_mail.php file to my account. I tested SMTP functionality, it worked fine, I configure SMTP plugin using information from test_mail.php and did not found any information about authentication. Moreover test_mail.php works without authentication.

Comment: @Alexander, Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the mail on the contact form is added as an authorized email sender on your hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress the default *CONFIG -> DISCUSSION* is applying the disallowed words list to the CF7 forms.

Try adding this code snippet to your theme functions.php file to block it from applying to CF7:

```
/**
 * CONTACT FORM 7
 * Disable WP Disallowed List for SPAM validation
 */
add_filter( 'wpcf7_submission_has_disallowed_words', '__return_false', 10, 2 );
```

It worked for me.